Movie from 2005-2012 where girl wakes up after stasis to a new world alone
I am trying to figure out the name of this movie I have only seen once. I am not exactly sure when it came out but I remember the following:

A man finding something like a meteorite or something. It started to grow like a plant, he took it from his shed to a junkyard. 
It turned out to be some sort of life pod because the world was apparently ending. He got into a fight with someone and saved his daughter inside of it.
At the end, the world is gone, but the girl went into stasis for a long time and woke up and left the pod to witness new beautiful world but everybody else was gone.
I am not quite sure if her boyfriend went with her, but I know that she survived and the pod also healed her when she was hurt.


Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Terminus (2015)
From Wikipedia:

Reports of a downed extraterrestrial object bring the attention of
  U.S. government agents. Although disappointed that they find no living
  specimens, the agents take an eyewitness into custody to observe him
  after they find he is no longer blind. Elsewhere, David Chamberlain, a
  mechanic who has not recovered from the death of his wife Jane,
  struggles to keep his job. Zach, a veteran of a war currently ongoing
  in Iran, asks for a job, though David must turn him down. David later
  helps Zach in a bar fight, learning that Zach is missing a leg. When
  David returns home, his daughter Annabelle tells him that his last two
  payments failed to go through, and she has been forced to return home
  from college.
Upset, David takes a car ride and crashes after seeing an object
  streak down from the sky. When David fails to return home to next
  morning, Annabelle looks for him. She finds him wandering near his
  crashed car and takes him to the hospital. A doctor informs Annabelle
  that David inexplicably has two functioning kidneys even though
  records show that one was removed in the past to transplant into his
  wife, which was rejected by her body which presumably lead to her
  death. Now obsessed with the object, David becomes convinced it is
  giving him instructions through his dead wife. Meanwhile, the agents
  supervise surgery on the eyewitness and argue with their supervisor to
  continue their research. He says the continuing war in Iran is
  necessary to raise the country's morale and takes precedence over any
  possible evidence of extraterrestrial contact.
David hires Zach to help him retrieve the object. As they do so, Zach
  touches it and becomes unnerved by the feedback. While protesting the
  advancing war amid reports that Russia, China, and France have
  threatened retaliation against the U.S. push into Iran, Zach
  experiences pain in his amputated leg. When he realizes that his leg
  is slowly regrowing, he returns to David to demand an explanation.
  David tells Annabelle and Zach about the object and insists that Zach
  must be brought into proximity with it. Zach's leg rapidly
  regenerates, causing him to join David's quest to create a large
  structure David believes the object wants built. They steal materials
  from a local junkyard, putting everything in an abandoned factory.
The agents, lured by reports of unexplained regeneration, come to
  David's house. Though David initially denies any knowledge, when they
  confront him with the hospital records, he says the object melted.
  Disbelieving him, the agents tail David, only to lose him when his
  friend Tony Cerillo helps. As the conflict in Iran escalates, David
  comes to believe the structure will save Annabelle from the oncoming
  nuclear war. When Cerillo investigates the missing materials from the
  junkyard, he confronts David, who accidentally kills him. Filled with
  remorse, David confides to Jane that he believes himself unworthy of
  the object, and she confirms that it was meant for others, whom David
  must assist.
Government scientists inform the agents that the object is an example
  of abiogenesis. Frustrated with delays, the agents return to David's
  house, where they take Zach and Annabelle hostage. David rescues them
  as they begin torturing Zach. As they escape, Agent Stipe shoots
  Annabelle, knowing David will return to the object to heal her.
  There, Agent Stipe shoots David. His subordinate, Agent Lubinski,
  objects, saying that the object should not be used to further the war
  effort. Zach, Stipe, and Lubinski engage in a firefight, and all are
  wounded. David helps Zach and Annabelle into the structure,
  apologizes for not being able to join them, and seals them in it just
  as a nuclear war begins. When Zach and Annabelle emerge, the world is
  in ruins.




